# Present Perfect usage instead of Past simple

Tags: present-perfect

I cannot understand why tutorials, examples, etc. contain examples like this:

*I have played*

or

*Have you been to Moscow?*

Why Past Simple cannot be used in these sentences? Where is the "border" when I can use Past Simple?

Comment: The phrase "I have played" is so short and devoid of context it's hard to say why the simple past could not have been used.

Answer (score 1):

We use the present perfect tense:

- for something that started in the past and continues in the present:
  oh! I have lost my phone!
- for something we have done several times in the past and continue to do
  when we are talking about our experience up to the present
- for something that happened in the past but is important at the time of speaking
- We often use the present perfect with time adverbials which refer to the recent past(just, only just, recently)
  or adverbials which include the present:
  ever (in questions), so far, until now,up to now, yet (in questions and negatives).
- We do not use the present perfect with an adverbial which refers to past time which is finished.

The past tense in English is used:

- to talk about the past
- to talk about hypotheses – things that are imagined rather than true.
- for politeness.

Comment: So, as I see, both events were in past: I played in something and I am not playing now. I was in Moscow, but now I'm in Berlin. Am I correct?

Comment: If the action is in the past and stopped in the past, that's simple past: I played ..
Have you been to Moscow? :  I have been to Moskow: something happend in the past and continues in the present.